# Why does my java variable say and stay 'Evaluating'?

Tags: java, android, debugging

**Problem**:
When I want to evaluate whether two List arrays are different, if I mouse over the variable it says "Evaluating..." and the Variables window says "Collecting Data.." and just stay there. I think this may be contributing to downstream issues.

**What I'm trying to do**:
The method below is to receive these two lists and evaluates value for value based upon position. I want to set a breakpoint to evaluate these values visually.

I'm using Intellij Idea 2021 with Android Studio plug-in with sdk version 29 (1.8)

```
private void checkForUpdates(List<String> original, List<String> update, int vNoteID)
```

[image: Collecting Data]

In the 15 minutes it took to write this I have yet to see the collected data. I'm not sure what I need to do.

Thanks!

Comment: The people who you're asking to answer your question can only go by the information that you share. That said, do you suppose indicating the IDE that you're using would help answer the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried researching more and I solved my problem by un-checking the "**Enable 'ToString()' object view:**" setting.

Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Debugger > Java (since I'm using Java)

[image: To Stop Collecting Data - Evaluating... during debugging]